# CherryPy with additional threads for custom jobs

Tags: python, multithreading, daemon, cherrypy

We're designing a system based on CherryPy that in addition to serving web requests needs to do tasks/jobs in parallel. We want it to be a single process running as a daemon and create threads for all the parallel jobs like scheduled tasks or collecting data online.

I've been browsing through the CherryPy documentation and know that it's thread-pooled creating threads for all user requests. However I can't seem to find documentation on how to create and manage threads for custom jobs. Does CherryPy have a thread-handler that we can hook in to or could/should we write our own handler that hooks into CherryPy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Subscribe a [Monitor](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/refman/process/plugins/index.html#cherrypy.process.plugins.Monitor) instance:

```
from cherrypy.process.plugins import Monitor

def foo():
    my.store.collect_data('things', 'stuff')

Monitor(cherrypy.engine, foo, frequency=300).subscribe()
```

This will run the `foo` function every 300 seconds in its own thread, and that thread will start when you call `engine.start` and stop when you call `engine.stop` (or at process exit).

Comment: The kwarg "interval" should be "frequency" in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to complete fumanchu's excellent answer by sharing the script I wrote for testing this before using it. It uses python bottle, proving the advice is also working with it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import bottle
import time
import threading
import cherrypy
from cherrypy.process.plugins import Monitor

srv = bottle.Bottle()
lock = threading.Lock()
x = 0
y = 0

def increment ():
    print("incrementing...")
    with lock:
        global x
        time.sleep(1)
        x += 1
    print("Done.")

monitor = Monitor(cherrypy.engine, increment, frequency=1)

@srv.get("/")
def read ():
    with lock:
        return "Got: %d %d." % (x, y)

@srv.post("/periodic/<x:int>")
def periodic (x):
    if x: monitor.start()
    else: monitor.stop()

@srv.put("/<V:int>")
def write (V):
    print("Serving")
    with lock:
        global x
        global y
        x = V
        time.sleep(5)
        y = V
        print("gtfo")
    return "OK. Current: %d." % x

srv.run(server='cherrypy')
```

#### Usage:

After enabling the server, use `curl http://localhost:8080` to read, `curl http://localhost:8080/<value>` to write some value (takes 5 seconds, while all the reads will be hanging), and finally `curl http://localhost:8080/periodic/0` and `curl http://localhost:8080/periodic/1` to disable/enable respectively the periodic write. Each write will take 1 second, during which reads and modifications will be hanging.

P.s. Working with python2 and python3